# SSIS: transfer parts of a database daily to a sql server 2012 with no direct connection

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I want to use SSIS to daily export/backup some tables from a production environment SQL Server 2012 database to a data warehouse integration environment. A direct connection between the two SQL Servers 2012 is not possible. 
What is the best way to do that? (The required tables are about 1GB of size, growing. The daily transfer will be organized by a different team. I need to generate a file to a directory. After it is transferred I need to restore/import it on the target sql server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one package that goes from ole db source to excel. Then create another package that goes from excel source to ole db destination. Test each package manually in ssis then create a SQL job to run the packages consecutively.

Comment: Are you sure excel is the best format for this project? What about sql server import/export?

Comment: Yes based on the information in your question the excel output and then input is the best way to automate this, in my opinion of course. You could do the export\import and then save it as a job but without a direct connection between the two databases it will be doing virtually the same thing as the ssis package and ssis is more robust for example you could add a polling step in ssis to ensure the file is there before running and even archive the file or audit to ensure it brought all rows from the file.

Comment: I found another solution. I created a second database on the same server. I use SSIS to daily insert the relevant tables with OLE DB. I created a daily compressed backup of the new database. The backup is transferred to the target server. This way I don't need to deal with many excel files.